# Deploying Rails App to AWS using capistrano, puma and nginx. Always show Welcome to nginx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, nginx, capistrano3, puma

Good day! I like to ask if someone encounter this issue, after the deployment of Rails app using Capistrano, Puma and NGINX. Welcome to nginx! page appear instead of Rails page root path? I tried to solve the issue but no luck. Hoping someone can help me. Thank you

Here's my nginx config

```
upstream app {
  # Path to Puma SOCK file, as defined previously
  server unix:/home/deploy/appname/shared/tmp/sockets/puma.sock fail_timeout=0;
}
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name localhost;
  root /home/deploy/appname/current/public;
  try_files $uri/index.html $uri @app;
  location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Connection '';
    proxy_pass http://app;
  }
  location ~ ^/(assets|fonts|system)/|favicon.ico|robots.txt {
    gzip_static on;
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
  }
  error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
  client_max_body_size 4G;
  keepalive_timeout 10;
}  

and cap deploy.rb

# config valid only for current version of Capistrano
lock "3.8.0"
set :application, 'appname'
set :branch, :aws_deployment_v1
set :repo_url, git repo link
set :deploy_to, '/home/deploy/appname'
set :pty, true
set :linked_files, %w{config/database.yml config/application.yml}
set :linked_dirs, %w{bin log tmp/pids tmp/cache tmp/sockets vendor/bundle public/system public/uploads}
set :keep_releases, 5
set :rvm_type, :user
set :rvm_ruby_version, 'ruby-2.1.6' # Edit this if you are using MRI Ruby
set :puma_rackup, -> { File.join(current_path, 'config.ru') }
set :puma_state, "#{shared_path}/tmp/pids/puma.state"
set :puma_pid, "#{shared_path}/tmp/pids/puma.pid"
set :puma_bind, "unix://#{shared_path}/tmp/sockets/puma.sock"    #accept array for multi-bind
set :puma_conf, "#{shared_path}/puma.rb"
set :puma_access_log, "#{shared_path}/log/puma_error.log"
set :puma_error_log, "#{shared_path}/log/puma_access.log"
set :puma_role, :app
set :puma_env, fetch(:rack_env, fetch(:rails_env, 'production'))
set :puma_threads, [0, 8]
set :puma_workers, 0
set :puma_worker_timeout, nil
set :puma_init_active_record, true
set :puma_preload_app, false
```

Comment: Is this the first time deployment to this stack? Because it sounds like a NGINX configuration issue

Comment: No, I have the same configuration on my previous rails app, i just rename the app name. My Previous deployment, work well. Don't know what happen on my current app.

Comment: kindly see my nginx config

Comment: upstream app {
  # Path to Puma SOCK file, as defined previously
  server unix:/home/deploy/appname/shared/tmp/sockets/puma.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

Comment: server {
  listen 80;
  server_name localhost;

  root /home/deploy/appname/current/public;

  try_files $uri/index.html $uri @app;

  location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Connection '';
    proxy_pass http://app;
  }

Comment: location ~ ^/(assets|fonts|system)/|favicon.ico|robots.txt {
    gzip_static on;
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
  }

  error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
  client_max_body_size 4G;
  keepalive_timeout 10;
}

Comment: You should add the configs to the question

Comment: and my capistrano deply.rb

Comment: how can i do that here on stackoverflow?

Comment: Click `edit` and then just append at the bottom

Comment: sorry, im not familiar here on stackoverflow add question

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried switching the `index.html` and the `@app` around?

```
try_files $uri @app $uri/index.html;
```